# Calculate an Qobjevo operator of qutip

Tags: qutip

I define a time-dependent operator in the form of an `Qobjevo` and pass it to `sesolve()` to solve for Schrodinger's equation. Below is an MWE.

```
from qutip import *
import numpy as np

tlist = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2)
H = [
    sigmaz(),
    [sigmax(), 'cos(t)']
]
psi0 = basis(2, 1)
result = sesolve(H, psi0, tlist)
```

Now I want to check the time-dependent Hamiltonian at given times in `tlist`. How do I get a list of Hamiltonians, each at time `tlist[i]`? Which qutip function can I refer to?

Comment: I guess you should give e_ops parameter in sesolve function